# How do I find token amount on Etherscan after the contract is deployed?

Tags: etherscan, ganache, web3-providers, deployed-bytecode

1. When I copy my connected test address from metamask onto etherscan the test tokens from Ganache do not show up.
2. After I deploy a contract, there is no etherscan address.
   Message: view on etherscan with a green checkmark...
   [block:1 txIndex:0]from: 0xdc3...51AF5to: SimpleStorage.(constructor)value: 0 weidata: 0x608...70033logs: 0hash: 0x8d2...ef1b0

Things I am using...

- Remix IDE
  -Solidity
  _0.8.7 compiler
  -simple storage contract
  -Ganache address

Comment: Where are you deploying your contract? On some local network or some public ETH test network?

Comment: It is not on the Ropsten, or Rinkeby Network. I somehow created my own network called Custom (5777) network.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are deploying to a local network (ganache CLI) instead of a testnet. If that is the case, then etherscan will not work. Instead, you should look into how to use Truffle, which is what I assume you are using if you're using Ganache:
https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts.html

If you want to use etherscan, then deploy to a public testnet like Rinkeby. I recommend that you figure out how to use the Truffle suite instead, however.